# Hidden account stuff in Scratch 3

Tags: mit-scratch

Scratch 3.2 is buggy, the biggest bug being that the search bar taking up half the nav bar. I wonder what causes this bug.

I restarted my [Chromebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromebook) and nothing happened. I cleared my cache and nothing happened. Nothing worked at all.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: I found [this bug report](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/687362/) on the Scratch forums. It links to projects with screenshots, like [this](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/855242895/) and [this](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/857823910/). It can be a temporary nuisance caused by a slow server or a slow internet connection. If it keeps bothering you, then it makes more sense to [report it to the Scratch Team](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/3/topic/add/). I don't see how the Stack Overflow community can help you with this.